# How to get the data from an Element

Tags: android, list, iteration, element, serializable

I have this code:

```
Serializable newList;
newList=extras.getSerializable("list");
Iterator<Element> itr =( (List<Element>) newList).iterator();
Element froga=null;
while (itr.hasNext()) {
    Object element = itr.next();
    Log.i("***Selected Tab", "Im currently in tab with index::" + element);
}
```

list is like this:  `HashMap < String, String >`

and is outputing this:

```
Im currently in tab with index::{L=blablabla, T=blablaba}
```

How can I select L?
**Can I select a specific element with something like an index?**

Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I would use the substring, since the output will always starts with "Im currently in tab with index::"
Then I would use something like

```
String str = "Im currently in tab with index::" + element;
int i = str.indexOf("index::{L="));
```

Then use a loop to grab the character after that index until you've reached the character comma then break out
for example:

```
String L ="";
int i = str.indexOf("index::{L="));
while(true){
   i++;
   if(str.charAt(i) == ',')
      break;
   L+=str.charAt(i+1);
}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: in fact, the only thing I have to care about is inside element which would output "{L=blablabla, T=blablaba}". The other part is just plain text I added to the log. I will try this method but I was looking for something else. thank you again!

Comment: in that case you can do int i = element.indexOf("{L=");

Comment: That is not working for me :( I  think I should have said that "list" has this form: <HashMap<String, String>>();

Comment: oh I thought element was a string, can you try String str = element.toString() to see if you can get the result in a string format?

Comment: Yes it works, but what if I would like to get the index? is that possible? Thank you!

Comment: will the element.toString() give you a string with a format like {L=blablabla, T=blablaba} ? or what is the format that it gievs back, can you give me an example?

Comment: in that case use the same code above, just modify it a little bit and you will get the value of L storing in the variable L as above

Answer (score 0):

I manage to do it like this, not sure if its the best way but it works.

```
                while (itr.hasNext()) {
                    element = itr.next();
                    entry = (HashMap<String, String>) element;
                    entry.get("T");//get variable

                }
```

Thank you